# language on google docs

Tags: google-docs

I am using Google Doc viewer to show online PDF url like this: https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf and I am using this URL using a javascript open window action like this:
window.open(url,target='_blank','width=800,height=600,scrollbars=1');

where URL is https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf

My question is: Google doc viewer takes language as English by default. Can I change this language somehow so that buttons next/previous on screen appear in Dutch and not in English?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `hl` query parameter to specify a different locale using ISO language codes. For instance, to use Dutch you should add `&hl=nl` as in the following link:

https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/viewer?url=www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf&hl=nl

Comment: This is perfect!! Works as I wanted. Thank you Claudio :)